# Python script to sum values from ls -l output

Tags: python, unix, dictionary, ls

From other post I could read the output of ls -l and filter only Bytes of files in a dir. But, I also want to put all those values into a list (array) and then get the total sum of elements.

I tried to create a list b and then print only the sum(b). But, when I want to create a list, I get MemoryError.

Situation Now:

```
import subprocess
import csv
process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l',], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.decode('ascii').splitlines(), delimiter = ' ', skipinitialspace=True, fieldnames= ['Owner','Date','Dir','Priv','Bytes','Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4', 'Field5'])
```

Issues start here

```
for row in reader:
    a = row['Bytes']
    b = [int(a)]
    for i in b:
        b.append(i)
    continue
    print(b)
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script2.py", line 13, in <module>
    b.append(i)
MemoryError
```

Any help how to put into one list all elements and then get sum would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `b.append(i)` tries to add `i` into `b`, you are trying to add `i` for each `i` in the array. And `continue` skips to the next loop, it will never print `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over `b` list and adding its elements to it, it will never stop.

```
for i in b:
    #b.append(i) #This is the problem
    #continue #Go to the next iteration
    print(i)
```

**Edit**:

```
for row in reader:
    a = row['Bytes']
    print(a)
    b.append(int(a))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this prints lists of 1 element reading from each row. And not one list that contains all elements from b[a]

Comment: Thanks, I changed:
        a = row['Bytes']
        b = [int(a)]
        for i in b:
                c.extend(b)
        continue
And it is giving the result...

Answer (score 1):

To make your list, you want to check if row['Bytes'] is null for each row, and, if not, convert to an integer.  A nice concise way to do this is with a list comprehension:

```
list_of_sizes = [int(row['Bytes']) for row in reader if row['Bytes']]
```

Or, the same thing, using a more traditional for-loop:

```
list_of_sizes = []
for row in reader:
    if row['Bytes']:
        list_of_sizes.append(int(row['Bytes']))
```

Then, you can use the sum function to calculate the sum:

```
total_size = sum(list_of_sizes)
```